# How to print group contents when there is no data in that group--Ireport

Tags: ireport

I need to print the group when there do not come record. I have actually added group which gets printed when the record fall in the very group ,but it does not get printed if it is blank. Can anyone tell me what could be the expression or any solution?

```
    <groupExpression>
            <![CDATA[(($F{GROUP_EXP}.doubleValue() >= new BigDecimal(250000).doubleValue() 
                     && $F{GROUP_EXP}.doubleValue() < new BigDecimal(500000).doubleValue() && $F{NE}.charAt(0)=='E'))]]>
   </groupExpression> 
   <groupHeader> 
        <band height="109"> 
             <printWhenExpression>
                  <![CDATA[(($F{GROUP_EXP}.doubleValue() >=new BigDecimal(250000).doubleValue() 
                            && $F{GROUP_EXP}.doubleValue() < new BigDecimal(500000).doubleValue() && $F{NE}.charAt(0)=='E'))]]>
             </printWhenExpression>
```

Comment: Here are the some lines as I am not able to show the complete code.

<groupExpression><![CDATA[(($F{GROUP_EXP}.doubleValue() >= new BigDecimal(250000).doubleValue() && $F{GROUP_EXP}.doubleValue() < new BigDecimal(500000).doubleValue()
    && $F{NE}.charAt(0)=='E'))]]></groupExpression>
  <groupHeader>
<band height="109">
<printWhenExpression><![CDATA[(($F{GROUP_EXP}.doubleValue() >=new BigDecimal(250000).doubleValue() && $F{GROUP_EXP}.doubleValue() < new BigDecimal(500000).doubleValue()
    && $F{NE}.charAt(0)=='E'))]]></printWhenExpression>
<staticText>

Comment: Please include your code inside your question.

Comment: First I would say thank you for your response. And I tried to include the code with  my question, but it got out of the scope and could not be published. Actually it is a long code with xml. My concerned is to add the condition which may print the group in ireport even if there is no record. I have added the above expression in "Group Expression and Print when Expression" in my group.